# HTML Radio Button Disable Automatic Selection On Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

This is the sample HTML form I am trying to use:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" id="one" value="one">One<br>
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" id="two" value="two">Two<br>

    <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="myFunction()">

    <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

And this is the sample JavaScript function I am trying to use:

```
function myFunction() {    
    if (document.getElementById("one").checked = true) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "One Selected";
    } else if (document.getElementById("two").checked = true) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Two Selected";
    }
}
```

So when the radio button "one" is clicked, it should display "One Selected" on the "output" and when the radio button "two" is clicked, it should display "Two Selected".
But, it is always automatically selecting the radio button "one" and displaying "One Selected" on the "output" even if I select the radio button "two" and submit it.
Why is this happening?
Also, is there a way for it to NOT automatically select the radio button "one" when the user hasn't selected any, so that it can display a message when neither of them are selected?

Answer (score 2):

`if` condition is wrong - you are assigning instead of checking the value. Use `==` or `===`. Here you are checking against radio button state - it already return either true or false.So u dont need a equal check.

```js
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("one").checked) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "One Selected";
    } else if (document.getElementById("two").checked) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Two Selected";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" id="one" value="one">One<br>
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" id="two" value="two">Two<br>

    <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="myFunction()">

    <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```